# return eloquent change without update the record on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

8 project 
everything working great so far 
i have this code

```
$item = $item_unit->getItem;
$item->item_smallest_unit_cost = $item_unit->item_unit_coast_price;
$item->item_smallest_unit_selling_price = $item_unit->item_unit_selling_price;
return $item->get();
```

as you can see i need to change the `item_smallest_unit_cost` and `item_smallest_unit_selling_price` and then return the item without update the original database but this code return the item with old item `item_smallest_unit_selling_price` and `item_smallest_unit_cost` 
i dont want to do this

```
$item = $item_unit->getItem;
$item->item_smallest_unit_cost = $item_unit->item_unit_coast_price;
$item->item_smallest_unit_selling_price = $item_unit->item_unit_selling_price;
$item->update // i dont want to do this but i want to return the item new changes
return $item->get();
```

any help here thanks

Comment: Can you `dd($item->item_smallest_unit_cost, $item_unit->item_unit_coast_price);` and provide what you get?

Comment: either you have to save it to database or you have to create a new variable that will hold the new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if data is not same with:

```
dd($item->item_smallest_unit_cost, $item_unit->item_unit_coast_price);
```

If is data you expected result, you need to save updated item:

```
$item = $item_unit->getItem;
$item->item_smallest_unit_cost = $item_unit->item_unit_coast_price;
$item->item_smallest_unit_selling_price = $item_unit->item_unit_selling_price;
$item->save(); // You need that
return $item;
```

This should work.

You can found more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models).

Answer (score 0):

`$item->item_smallest_unit_cost = $item_unit->item_unit_coast_price;
$item->item_smallest_unit_selling_price = $item_unit->item_unit_selling_price;`

instead of this use following

```
$item['item_smallest_unit_cost'] = $item_unit->item_unit_coast_price;
$item['item_smallest_unit_selling_price'] = $item_unit->item_unit_selling_price;
```

also

```
return $item->get();
```

instead only

```
return $item;
```